# Loading custom.css after PJS.Bootstrap default css in Orchard

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.8

So we have created a our own theme in Orchard CMS using CodeGen. And we're using PJS.Bootstrap on top of it. Now my task is to create a custom.css file in Theme's Style to do some basic styling. For this i added Style.Include("custom.css"); in the layout.cshtml file in Views of our theme. The file is getting loaded but before the Bootstrap's default css, like shown below:

```
<link href="/Themes/OurTheme/Styles/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="/Themes/PJS.Bootstrap/Styles/site-default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Any way i load our css after the PJS.Bootstrap default css?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the *Layout.cshtml* but *CustomResources.cshtml* to load your custom resources. Just check for the file in the *PJS.Bootstrap/Views* folder.

Either insert your resources directly in there, or override it with an alternate in another custom theme inheriting from PJS.Boorstrap.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Xceno, there is no file named CustomResources.cshtml, there is Resources.cshtml file which seems to load all the PJS.Boostrap stuff, i copied it in to our Theme project and added Style.Include("custom.css"); -- rebuild the solution but still if i see the page source, default.min.css being loaded after our custom.css. Any ideas?

Comment: For future readers, the file is Resources.cshtml, it didn't work on my machine but magically worked on a different one, but yes that's the solution what Xceno suggested.